# Change scala type specification to java type specification

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, types

How to change all variable with scala type (like Boolean)  to java type  (like `java.lang.Boolean`). Because when using scala type I get an error:

[image]

That is dissapear when I change to java type:

[image]

But I dont want to typing all variable with scala `Boolean` sepecification  to `java.lang.Boolean` because that too long. Whereas scala IDE automatically assume variabel declared with `Boolean` is a scala type. I mean is there any shortcut for this. For example in python there are something like `import A.B.C as initial1`. Or Is possible to change default variable declaration  from scala type to java type in eclipse IDE.

And then why that  error occur? I write this snippet:

```
object CompatibleTest extends App{

  println("test compatible")

  val m = new java.lang.Boolean(true)

  if(m.isInstanceOf[Boolean]) println("yes... ")

}
```

that indicate both `java.lang.Boolean` and scala `Boolean` are the same type.

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
import java.lang.{Boolean => jBoolean}
```

to save typing.  Shadowing the Scala `Boolean` with Java's is not likely to work out well for you.

Note also that Scala boxes its `Boolean` (which is Java's primitive `boolean`) into `java.lang.Boolean` in generic code and a few other contexts, including `isInstanceOf` tests.